# Defining print()-like functions for a new type in Julia

Tags: printing, julia

In order to make a new type printable in Julia, which methods should one define? I believe that one should only define `show`, which will then induce the behavior of other functions like:

- print
- string
- repl_show
- showcompact
- showall

Which of these methods need to be defined for a new type?

Answer (score 10):

If the Base source is any reliable reference, `base/version.jl` has only `print()` and `show` defined (and `show` depends on `print`)

```
function print(io::IO, v::VersionNumber)
    print(io, v.major)
    print(io, '.')
    print(io, v.minor)
    print(io, '.')
    print(io, v.patch)
    if !isempty(v.prerelease)
        print(io, '-')
        print_joined(io, v.prerelease,'.')
    end
    if !isempty(v.build)
       print(io, '+')
       print_joined(io, v.build,'.')
    end
end
show(io, v::VersionNumber) = print(io, "v\"", v, "\"")
```

It seems at this point it is up to you if you want to rely on one common function;
you just implement all such functions that way. Example:

```
type Foo
end
import Base.string
function string(x::Foo)
    return "a Foo()"
end
import Base.print
print(io::IO, x::Foo) = print(io, string(x))
import Base.show
show(io::IO, x::Foo) = print(io, "This is ", x)
```

-

```
julia> f = Foo()
This is a Foo()
```

Comment: this answer is outdate? Can we modernise it?